# Why did Avatar Korra still hallucinate her battle with Zaheer even though all the poison was out?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

Why did Avatar Korra still hallucinate her battle with Zaheer even though Toph extracted all the poison from her?

Comment: Trauma, and more specifically CPTSD, is not cured as soon as physical ailments are treated. That's why therapy exists and is a long, drawn-out process.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Kadima in the comments - Korra was still suffering from the trauma of her battle with Zaheer. Getting the poison out helped her physical abilities to a point, but Korra still needed to *mentally* come to terms with her loss against Zaheer before being able to bend like she used to.